# Possible to detect paused state of MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have multiple media players where each player is player after another. So I have to detect which player was paused to continue playback on that specific player.

I tried to detect which player is paused, but `MediaPlayer` has only `isPlaying()` method, which does not help me in this case.

Is there a way to detect if and what `MediaPlayer` object has been paused?

Note: I thought of introducing another `boolean` value to help me in this case, but I first want to check if there is a way to detect paused state with the default objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by introducing a new `boolean` variable for **each `MediaPlayer` object**.

Then I later simply checked if the boolean value of that object is false or true.

```
boolean mIsPaused[];

//... later in the code
player[i].pause();
mIsPaused[i] = true;

//...even later more
player[i].start();
mIsPaused[i] = false;
```

So far, this satisfies my need and I see no slowdowns.